# What to expect from Interpreter["Expression"]?

Tags: functions, documentation, free-form-input, interpreter

Sometimes it works ok

```
Interpreter["Expression"]["1"]
```

> 1

sometimes not:

```
Interpreter["Expression"]["Graphics[{}]"]
```

[image]

Why doesn't it work for the second case? What is the rule of thumb here?

Comment: Works on `"plot[Sin[x],{x,0,10}]"`, fails on `"Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,10}]"`.  Work on `"plot"`, fails on `"Plot"`. Maybe certain symbols are disallowed for security or something like that.

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes, makes sense but it seems to be be quite sensitive which makes it pretty useless for a general scenario. Unless well documented.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In interpreting an expression, only some symbols are allowed. A list of allowed symbols may be found (V11.2) with:

```
Interpreter["Expression"]["1"]; (* to autoload code *)
Internal`CheckCache[
 Interpreter`Transform`PackagePrivate`iInterpreterObject[
   "Expression", <|"Parser" -> 
     Interpreter`PackageScope`expressionParser, 
    "iRestrictionFunction" -> 
     Interpreter`PackageScope`expressionRestriction|>][
  "SymbolRestriction"]] // Sort
```

`` System` `` symbols not on this list seem to be disallowed.  Also other symbols not in the `` Global` `` context seem to be disallowed.

Interesting inclusions/omissions:

```
Interpreter["Expression"]["AiryAiZero"]
Interpreter["Expression"]["AiryAi"]
Interpreter["Expression"]["\[FormalX]"]
Interpreter["Expression"]["foo`x"]
(*
  Failure[..]
  AiryAi
  Failure[..]
  Failure[..]
*)
```

It may be there are other rules in play, but this is my first approximation.

---

*Update: Workarounds.*
If you wish to throw caution to the wind, you can override the security check at your own risk:

```
Block[{Security`InsecureExprQ = False &},
 Interpreter["Expression"]["Graphics[{}]"]
 ]
```

Targeting exceptions. `` Security`InsecureExprQ `` does have hooks to allow/disallow specific symbols and contexts:

```
Security`$AllowedContexts
Security`$AllowedSymbols
Security`$DisallowedContexts
Security`$DisallowedSymbols
```

However `Interpreter` overrides these.  So we can override `Interpreter` with the [Villegas-Gayley trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656).  Since `Interpreter` passes the second element `allowedSymbols` with a head of `HoldComplete` and the other three as `Lists`, you have to do the same.

```
interp[s_String,
  {allowedContexts_, allowedSymbols_, disallowedContexts_, disallowedSymbols_}] :=
 Internal`InheritedBlock[{Security`InsecureExprQ},
  Security`InsecureExprQ[e_HoldComplete, data_] /; ! TrueQ[$in] := 
   Block[{$in = True},
    Security`InsecureExprQ[e,
     MapThread[Join,
      {data,
       {allowedContexts, allowedSymbols, disallowedContexts, disallowedSymbols}}]]
    ];
  Interpreter["Expression"][s]
  ];
```

None of the graphics primitives and directive are on the default allowed list, so we have to add all we use:

```
interp["Graphics[{Text[Style[foo`x,Large],{0,0}]},Frame->True]",
 {{"foo`"}, HoldComplete[Graphics, Text, Style, Large, Frame], {}, {}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 Recommend that you use `Sort` to make the list easier to use.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, Bob.  I might use `MemberQ`, too.

Comment: Btw, I meanwhile found and use `Interpreter[Restricted["Expression", All]]["Print[1]"]`. It is undocumented ofc :) but you can add it for completeness.

Comment: Also, Internal`CheckCache piece does not seem to work in 12.1